# Increasing the plot area in ggplot to cope with geom_text at plot edges

Tags: r, plot

How do I increase the grey plot area of a chart with one factor based axis and one numerical axis so that text labels in `geom_text()` plots are in view and do not extend outside the plot area?

[image: ggplot showing geom_text() plot where labels extend outside the plot area]

In particular, I would like to extend the grey area to provide a margin area within the plot area that allows the text labels to appear in full.

Or is there a better way?

Comment: You could try the `expand` argument to `scale_x_discrete` and/or `scale_y_continuous`. It takes a numeric vector of length 2, the first being a factor for expansion and the second being an additive expansion. Try different values to see what works well.

Comment: I wish that Fellow's wordcloud was compatible with ggplot2 as his updated version deals specifically with this: http://blog.fellstat.com/?p=248

Comment: @BrianDiggs Thanks for that tip. `expand` seems to do the trick, though I think some tweaking of styles is then required as a result... I'm trying `theme_bw()` to start with...

Answer (score 4):

You can change the layout option of each ggplot using `ggplot_gtable`, then display all plots using `grid.arrange`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
## create a dummy ggplot
(g1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
       geom_text(aes(label=rownames(mtcars)), size=6, angle=45) +
       theme(plot.margin = unit(rep(1, 4), "cm")))
```

Obviously the text labels do not extend outside the plot area. But the following code allows just that:

```
gg_table <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g1))
gg_table$layout$clip[gg_table$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gg_table)
```

Create a gg_table for each panel, then use `grid.arrange` to display all:

```
grid.arrange(gg_table, gg_table, gg_table, gg_table, ncol=2)
```

[image]

I know this is labor intensive, but you can write a function to create multiple ggplots and gg_tables to save time.